# jQuery autocomplete with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want to implement an autocomplete feature with images in my website.

I would like to use the jQuery autocomplete plugin.

I had a look at their sample code.

Can anyone explain me what the below code means in $(document).ready() event:

```
$("#imageSearch").autocomplete("images.php", {
  width: 320,
  max: 4,
  highlight: false,
  scroll: true,
  scrollHeight: 300,
  formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
    return "<img src='images/" + value + "'/> " + value.split(".")[0];
  },
  formatResult: function(data, value) {
    return value.split(".")[0];
  }
});
```

My ultimate requirement is when I type some letters in the text box, I want the options to come with an image associated with it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use this for reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

---

```
$("#imageSearch").autocomplete("images.php", {
```

Apply pluging autocomplete to all fields #imageSearch. First parameter I guess it the page that generates the response based on what is entered (images.php);

```
        width: 320,
```

Width of the drop down

```
        max: 4,
```

Maximum suggestions

```
        highlight: false,
```

Highlight true/false

```
        scroll: true,
```

Scroll bar aka drop-down kind of list, or just a long div under.

```
        scrollHeight: 300,
```

Height of the auto complete drop down.

```
        formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
            return "<img src='images/" + value + "'/> " + value.split(".")[0];
        },
```

How to format the response returned from *images.php*.

```
        formatResult: function(data, value) {
             return value.split(".")[0];
        }
```

How to return the value, if the user selects one of the choices.

```
});
```

Closing brackets :p

Comment: When user clicks on any of the option ,i want to call another page where should i override ?

Comment: Late reply, but you can find the answer in the abovementioned documentation - http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Answer (score 4):

This is about the Jquery Autocomplete PLUGIN, there is no such option as formatItem and formatValue in the actual Jquery UI Autocomplete.

I suggest people to read this http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide which explain how to migrate from the old plugin version to the official UI widget.

To get you autocomplete working with image in the suggest list you should read this thread: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-html-in-autocomplete