# Autocomplete JQuery plugin with images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the JQuery autocomplete plugin with images in the result. For example, if I search Mario, in the result I should see IMAGE Mario. I found lot of example but with no success

This is the code that I found:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    delay: 10,
    minLength: 0,                                          
    source: updates,        
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
}).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li />")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a><img src='" + item.icon + "' />" + item.label + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: Maybe you could specify the problem better, share what you already have and what is not working? It is going to be very hard to help you with that scarce information.

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far. edit your question and include the code that you have tried.

Comment: I updated the post with the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911537/jquery-autocomplete-with-images?rq=1

Comment: I already saw the link but I don't know what should I write in images.php